# Sender Address rejected. Django + webfaction email

Tags: python, django, webfaction

The code I am using is what I found on [webfaction](http://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/config.html#configuring-django-to-send-mail)

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.webfaction.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<mailbox name>'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<mailbox pass>'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '<email address>'
SERVER_EMAIL = '<email address>'
```

I keep on getting the error SMTPRecipientsRefused

Sender address rejected: need fully-qualified address

Comment: Well, you actually have to use real input for those lines. `'<email address>'` is indeed not a fully-qualified address.

Comment: For me I got this error when I did not have `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` set in settings.py

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the problem, it was not in the settings, the settings are correct, it was while sending the actual email in views.py I used a different email address in the from_email field.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you have not configured well your settings on [webfaction](https://www.webfaction.com/) control panel.

You have to follow these steps described in the [docs](http://docs.webfaction.com/user-guide/email.html)

1. Create a mailbox
2. Create an email address
3. Link your address to your mailbox

In my code I have this:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.webfaction.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'infomailbox'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<<mine>>'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'info@example.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'info@example.com'
```

It works perfect for me.

Comment: I did exactly that. Still getting the same error. Also, if I hadn't done that, I would have an authentication error not a "Sender address rejected"

Comment: DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL worked for me